# get 0 when selecting contact from contact list

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have made a application in which i want to user to select the contact from the contact list and display it in the EditText.But when ever my user selects a contact my edit text value shows only 0.Why this so???

Code

```
case R.id.bt_contacts:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                break; 

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                contactNumber = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }

            etMobile.setText("" + contactNumber);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should get string value from cursor

```
contactNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
```

Comment: I think you're right: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html

Comment: Nah it giving me # now